# Advice needed on text analytics (keyword/topic extraction, sentiment analysis) with multiple language support

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I am looking for a text analytics solution which supports the following at the minimum.

1. Keyword extraction from provided text
2. Multiple language support (At the minimum, English and Chinese)
3. Sentiment analysis

So far, I have looked into AWS comprehend, GCP natural language AI, Azure text analytics, Natural library (nodejs), Zoho Catalyst and Rosette. I am unable to make up my mind due to following reasons.

1. Zoho has keyword extraction and sentiment analysis but no support for multiple languages.
2. Rosette also has English only keyword extraction. Same with Natural library.
3. AWS, Azure and GCP seem to have all but not exactly the way I need. Comprehend provides only batch processed topic/keyword detection whereas I need on a more dynamic basis where as soon as I have some text, I need the data. Azure provides key phrases from the provided text which is slightly different from keywords/topics. GCP does tokenisation so it provides list of words enriched with syntactic information. I like how Zoho does it - https://catalyst.zoho.com/sdk/nodeJS-sdk/keyword-extraction.html